# How to add info to the AD users with powershell from a CSV sheet

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Let's say I have an CSV sheet, first line with the usernames and the second with the emailadresses.

Example:

Username  Emailadress

---

jhornet   jhornet@mail.com

How can I import this info to the AD within a safe and nice way, maybe with a check in it?

This is what I have till now (without CSV):

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$company = "International"
$username = Get-Content c:\users.txt
$emailadress = Get-Content c:\mail.txt

foreach($user in $username)
{
 Set-ADuser -Identity $user -Company $company
}

#second

foreach($emailadress in $username)
{
Set-ADuser -Identity $user -EmailAddress $emailadress
}
```

Still learning a lot with powershell, some things are just hard to understand and better to see :)

Thanks in advance!

Gr,

JPA

Comment: If you have a CSV file then use `Import-Csv` to read the file.  That will produce one or more objects with properties corresponding to the CSV field names.

Comment: Ok thanks!

I have this now, still doesn't work, but I am almost there (i hope)

Import-Module activedirectory

Import-Csv C:\user.csv

$company = "International"

foreach($user in $username)
{
 Set-ADuser -Identity $user -Company $company
}

#second

foreach($emailadress in $username)
{
Set-ADuser -Identity $user -EmailAddress $emailadress
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out on a shaky limb here because I've never used the AD commands before but it should go something like this:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$company = "International"
$users = Import-Csv c:\user.csv
$users # dumps users to allow visual inspection
read-host "press Enter to continue or Ctrl+C to abort"
$users | Foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.username -Company $company -whatif}
$users | Foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.username -EmailAddress $_.emailaddress -whatif}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter when you think the commands are going to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Keith!

Still doesn't work, to bad. Checked my CSV file and that seems to be correct.

Thinking thinking...

Comment: "Still doesn't work"..... You might want to update your question with the error message that appears. Also, a sample of the csv would be great as Keith is currently working in the blind. The original csv-sample in the question is not a csv-sample.

Comment: Sorry for that!

The CSV looks like this

username emailadress
cursus1       cursus1@test.org
cursus2       cursus2@test.org
cursus3       cursus3@test.org

When I do an "Import-CSV" cmd, it looks good in the console, I get no error. But when I run the script, it only adds "cursus3" (without mailadress, just cursus3) at the cursus3 account in the emailadress field.

Comment: Is that really `emailadress` with only one `d`?  If so, adjust the line above to `$_.emailadress`.

Comment: Yes with one "D", I get this error>

Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EmailAdress'.
At line:8 char:52
+ $users | Foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.username -EmailAdress $_.emailadress - ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: As per the error. Set-ADUser doesn't have a parameter called "EmailAdress". The parameter name is -EmailAddress.
Reference: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

Comment: No, I meant that your CSV file's field is emailadress with only one `d`.  PowerShell parameters are usually spelled correctly.  :-)

Comment: Keith, very awkward but the "emailadress" seems to be the problem, In the CSV and the script, both was wrong spelled.. LOL.

Edited it and it works great now! Thanks for your help, this helps me a lot! big time!

Greetings